# Equivalent of % movement for Python files

Tags: python, vim

For languages with `{}` to denote blocks, vim has the almighty `%` key.  What is the equivalent movement thing for python code?  Or at least to move to next / previous line with the same indent.

Comment: Why not just download a python plugin?

Comment: *Or at least to move to next/previous line with the same indent* - could you elaborate what you mean with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_to_next/previous_line_with_same_indentation) suggest bindings such as:

```
nnoremap <M-,> k:call search('^'. matchstr(getline(line('.')+1), '\(\s*\)') .'\S', 'b')<CR>^
nnoremap <M-.> :call search('^'. matchstr(getline(line('.')), '\(\s*\)') .'\S')<CR>^
```

As well as offering a more comprehensive solution:

```
" Jump to the next or previous line that has the same level or a lower
" level of indentation than the current line.
"
" exclusive (bool): true: Motion is exclusive
" false: Motion is inclusive
" fwd (bool): true: Go to next line
" false: Go to previous line
" lowerlevel (bool): true: Go to line with lower indentation level
" false: Go to line with the same indentation level
" skipblanks (bool): true: Skip blank lines
" false: Don't skip blank lines
function! NextIndent(exclusive, fwd, lowerlevel, skipblanks)
  let line = line('.')
  let column = col('.')
  let lastline = line('$')
  let indent = indent(line)
  let stepvalue = a:fwd ? 1 : -1
  while (line > 0 && line <= lastline)
    let line = line + stepvalue
    if ( ! a:lowerlevel && indent(line) == indent ||
          \ a:lowerlevel && indent(line) < indent)
      if (! a:skipblanks || strlen(getline(line)) > 0)
        if (a:exclusive)
          let line = line - stepvalue
        endif
        exe line
        exe "normal " column . "|"
        return
      endif
    endif
  endwhile
endfunction

" Moving back and forth between lines of same or lower indentation.
nnoremap <silent> [l :call NextIndent(0, 0, 0, 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> ]l :call NextIndent(0, 1, 0, 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [L :call NextIndent(0, 0, 1, 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> ]L :call NextIndent(0, 1, 1, 1)<CR>
vnoremap <silent> [l <Esc>:call NextIndent(0, 0, 0, 1)<CR>m'gv''
vnoremap <silent> ]l <Esc>:call NextIndent(0, 1, 0, 1)<CR>m'gv''
vnoremap <silent> [L <Esc>:call NextIndent(0, 0, 1, 1)<CR>m'gv''
vnoremap <silent> ]L <Esc>:call NextIndent(0, 1, 1, 1)<CR>m'gv''
onoremap <silent> [l :call NextIndent(0, 0, 0, 1)<CR>
onoremap <silent> ]l :call NextIndent(0, 1, 0, 1)<CR>
onoremap <silent> [L :call NextIndent(1, 0, 1, 1)<CR>
onoremap <silent> ]L :call NextIndent(1, 1, 1, 1)<CR>
```

Which uses:

- `[l` and `]l` jump to the previous or the next line with the same indentation level as the current line.
- `[L` and `]L` jump to the previous or the next line with an indentation level lower than the current line.

Answer (score 3):

Vim has the `{` and `}` motions to move between "paragraphs" and the corresponding `p` text-object (`vip`, `dap`).

The default Python ftplugin also (re)defines `[[` and `]]` to move to next and previous class and `]m` and `[m` to move to next and previous method.

The [indent-object](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037) is *very* useful as well for Python.

Comment: pardon me, but what is indent-object?  Links please?

Comment: Sorry, I had the URL in my clipboard but I forgot to put it in the answer. It's very easy to find, though.

Comment: Pretty cool but indent-object does not work in normal mode. Is there any way to force it to work in normal mode ?

Comment: @emmasculateur, I'm not sure what you mean: that plugin does what it's supposed to do: `vii`, `dii`, `cii`, `yii`, `=ii`, `>ii`, `<ii`, `vai`, `dai`, `cai`, `yai`, `=ai`, `>ai`, `<ai`…

Comment: @romainl `vii` will select a block, `yii` copy it, `=ai` indent it, etc. I just want to _move_ to the beginning/end of the block in normal mode. The first answer gives a solution but `[L` and `]L` don't work for me so I thought this plugin could help.

Comment: @emmasculateur, yeah, that's not the purpose of that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use comments to insert {} (would not do this if others share):

```
class Game(object): # {
    def __init__(self, num, end): # {
        pass
    # }
# }
```

Comment: Ugh, I hope I never encounter such a coding style.

Comment: Just got a down vote without comment.  I understand the coding style is not pleasant.  I did say I would not do this if sharing code.  The coding style is allows for `%` movement in vim.