# Move to the next row which has non-white space character in the same column in VIM?

Tags: vim

As source code is usually indented, it will help navigate source code quickly if I can move to the next/previous row which has non-empty white character in the same column. Using below code snippet as example and the cursor in on the last `}`, is there a way to navigate the cursor to i which starts `if`?

```
if (condition) {
    //  some code
}
```

Comment: See also [Equivalent of % movement for Python files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16883360).

Comment: Related: [How to move vertically until reaching a non-whitespace character?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/120/467) at Vi SE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To search for the same screen column, you can use the special `/\%v` atom; the current column can be queried with `virtcol('.')`. Assert a non-whitespace (`\S`) at that position, and trigger a `b`ackwards `search()` for it:

```
:call search('\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v\S', 'bW')
```

You can easily turn this into a normal-mode mapping.

Comment: Thanks. Did the mapping for Control-k: `:map <C-k> :call search('\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v\S', 'bW')<CR>` and Control-j: `:map <C-j> :call search('\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v\S', 'wW')<CR>`.

Answer (score 2):

I've now implemented this motion in my [JumpToVerticalOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4841); by default mapped to `]|` / `[|`. There are other, related mappings like a `]V{char}` mapping that works just like `f`, but vertically.

So if you don't mind installing a plugin (plus dependencies), this is more robust and functional (it supports `[count]` as well).

Comment: Do you think map them to `<C-j>` and `<C-k>`, which is more easy to hit and understand.

Comment: You can remap them; for me personally, `<C-j/k>` is too valuable for such rarely used (by me) motion.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but if you start at `}` and hit `%`, the cursor moves to the matching `{`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, using `%` then `^` might workaround it, but it would be limited to block code, beside the extra key stroke. It would be great if there could be a generic shortcut.

Comment: `but it would be limited to block code` what do you mean? this answer does what you wanted, as you described in your question (with that example). and yes, `%0` or `%^` two key strokes.

Comment: @Kent, I meant there might be no "{" and "}" to block the code, the the code is still indented.

Answer (score 1):

If your code has a defined indentation system, [jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise) works well for relative, absolute, or block-scope movements across indented blocks.