# Vim vertical motion: moving up/down-ward, to the first line with a non-blank character on the current position

Tags: vim

Trying to move to the first (or [count]th) line upward or downward, on a line with a non-blank character in the current horizontal position, would seem useful for well indented code.

### Example

In Python

```
if condition_a:
    do_stuff()
    ''' random number of lines
elif condition_b:
    other_stuff()
else:
    raise Exception("No stuff to be done.")
```

Lets say the cursor is on 'i' from `if`. It could be great to move it to 'e' from `elif` with a vertical motion.

Reading `:help up-down-motions` did not seems to provide any pointer for this question.

Is it possible to achieve such motions ?

Comment: you can create a map for the `/^\S` to make it easy to use. I put it as comment instead of answer, because, `if -else ` pairs are not always at the BOL. it could be somewhere in the middle of a line. In that case, if you want to from `if` jump to the corresponding `else`, the `/^\S` won't work. I am not sure if it is part of your requirement.

Comment: @Kent The `if` `else` was for illustration purpose only, I am just trying to achieve what is stated in the title  ;) So if it does just that, it definitely should be an answer ! On the other hand, blindly entering the sequence of 4 characters you proposed did not do the trick for me : it is in fact looking for the next line not starting with a space, which is not related.

Comment: See also [Equivalent of % movement for Python files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16883360).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [JumpToVerticalOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4841) has (among others) a `[|` / `]|` motion that jumps to the [count]'th next line that has non-whitespace in the same column as the current one.